# NoMethodError (undefined method `permit'for # <Array: 0x000056147c82b630>): When sending parameters to Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, vue.js, nuxt.js

## What I want to come true

I'm trying to send a parameter to Rails, which is a server, but Rails' strong parameters don't work because the underlying data is an array.
In this case, do I need to change the array to an object and send the value? What are the best practices in that case?

#Code

JavaScript

```js
 update (context) {
    const list = context.state.todos.list
    const bookId = context.state.book.selectedBook.id
// Extracting values ​​from an array　with map
    const post =
    list.map((item) => {
      return {
        content: item.content,
        status: false
      }
    })
    this.$axios.$patch(url.POST_API + 'posts/' + bookId, {
      post
    })
```

```rb
     def update
        post = Post.find(params[:id])
        post.post_items.update(content_params)
     end
     

        private
            def content_params
                params.require(:post).permit(:content, :status)
            end

end
```

## Error

```
api_1    | Started PATCH "/api/v1/posts/17" for 172.28.0.1 at 2021-09-05 16:51:13 +0900
api_1    | Processing by Api::V1::PostsController#update as HTML
api_1    |   Parameters: {"post"=>[{"content"=>"Test", "status"=>false}], "id"=>"17"}
api_1    |   Post Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 17], ["LIMIT", 1]]
api_1    |   ↳ app/controllers/api/v1/posts_controller.rb:23:in `update'
api_1    | Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 15ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms | Allocations: 1862)
api_1    | 
api_1    | 
api_1    |   
api_1    | NoMethodError (undefined method `permit' for #<Array:0x000056147cdd5a90>):
api_1    |   
api_1    | app/controllers/api/v1/posts_controller.rb:39:in `content_params'
api_1    | app/controllers/api/v1/posts_controller.rb:24:in `update'
```

## What I tried myself

To change an array to an object
I used Object.asign, but it didn't work because the index number was added.

```
parameters: {"post"=>{"0"=>{"content"=>"テスト", "status"=>false}}, "id"=>"16"}
```

```
update (context) {
const list = context.state.todos.list
const bookId = context.state.book.selectedBook.id

//Changed post to content
const content =
list.map((item) => {
return {
content: item.content,
status: false
}
})
const post = Object.assign({}, content) //Add
this.$axios.$patch(url.POST_API + 'posts/' + bookId, {
post
})
}
}
```

Comment: Your params are coming through as an array. They need to be a hash for `permit` to work

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I used Object.assign to change it to an object but it didn't work. Where can I find the correct information?

Comment: try to stringify the post in your patch request, something like this JSON.stringify(post)

Comment: This code won't work even if you were to solve the whitelisting issue. #update is an method on model instances - not on associations. If you want to update multiple nested records at once you need to use nested attributes or just rethink the code and update the post_items one at a time. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#update

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Sure, there are no errors, but the value could not be updated. Use the update_all in the link you posted to fix the problem.